# R data.table: Convert a character string to numeric, using only data.table syntax (=, :=) not <-, $

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to set a character string to numeric in a data table using only data table syntax, i.e. without using data$variable.name or '<-'

```
sapply(tm[, store.latitude], function(x)as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

I tried this but it‘s not changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just use `type.convert`

```
library(data.table)
tm[, store.latitude = type.convert(store.latitude)]
```

Or for multiple columns

```
tm[, (cols) := type.convert(.SD, as.is = TRUE), .SDcols = cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only one column named `store.latitude`, you could use :

```
library(data.table)
tm[, store.latitude := as.numeric(as.character(store.latitude))]
```

If there are lot of columns that you want to change which are stored as character vector in `cols`.

```
tm[,(cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))),.SDcols = cols]
```